# ID not found when trying to add fragment dynamically in android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am building an android application which requires fragment transactions. For these to work (replacing, removing, adding fragments) later at runtime, I was told that you need to dynamically add the original fragments to the activity in order to manipulate them later. This doesn't look difficult, yet I am running into a **confusing error:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c008b (com.powerofpixels.magpie:id/auth_fragment_container) for fragment AuthOptionsFragment{fa0ffa7 #0 id=0x7f0c008b}
```

So android can't find the fragment container to add dynamically to the activity, but why?

**Here is my AuthActivity.java:**

```
package com.powerofpixels.magpie.ui.activity;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.powerofpixels.magpie.R;
import com.powerofpixels.magpie.ui.fragment.AuthOptionsFragment;


public class AuthActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private static final String TAG = AuthActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_auth);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.auth_fragment_container, new AuthOptionsFragment()).commit();


    }
}
```

**Here is my AuthActivity xml ressource file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".ui.activity.AuthActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/logo_image_view"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**And voici the fragment xml ressource file:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.powerofpixels.magpie.ui.fragment.AuthOptionsFragment"
    android:id="@+id/auth_fragment_container">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/sign_up_text_view"
        android:textSize="22dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Log in"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/log_in_text_view"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sign_up_text_view"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/skip_text_view"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/skip_text_view" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Skip"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/skip_text_view"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/log_in_text_view"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sign_up_text_view"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/sign_up_text_view" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

So what's the deal here?

Thanks.

Comment: The container to hold the fragment does not go in the fragment's layout file but the activity's. Also, the container should not include other UI elements in it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".ui.activity.AuthActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/logo_image_view"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context=".ui.activity.AuthActivity">
 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/auth_fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
 />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your AuthActivity should have a fragment container (most often it's a FrameLayout) where you define a container id. That id you'll use in Fragment transaction.